I'm having reliability issues with using C# REST Sharepoint API for bulk updates on a list
My calls to the Sharepoint REST API with my C# application are working. Some of the time. Other times I will call ExecuteQuery and they throw exceptions with unhelpful messages like "Could not complete the operation. Please try again."
My application is a console application designed to run every so often and do a bulk update to a list based on the contents of another list. Is there a better way to deal with bulk updates than updating a batch of items with UpdateItem or DeleteItem and then calling the method below? Using ExecuteQueryWithRetries also results in odd behavior where it appears to stop retrying if it hits an actual error message of any kind.
public static bool ExecuteQueryWithRetry(ClientContext? context, int numRetries)
{
    bool success = false;
    int timesRetried = 0;
    while (!success && (timesRetried < numRetries))
    {
        try
        {
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (ServerException e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            timesRetried++;
        }
    }
    return success;
}


This is the package I am using in my application: using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
